# Count Occurrences of an Item in a List using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to calculate the occurrences of an Item in a list using LINQ,

I have the following schema -

User (All Entries Provided), Count (To be Calculated)

The count should be like -

[image]

I cannot think of an elegant solution to this.

Is it even possible only using LINQ? If not, how can we achieve this using LINQ with some C# Code.

Comment: What is your expected output? The count (not sum) of occurrences grouped by user, or an additional column with the occurrence count?

Comment: It looks like `GroupBy` will easily let you count the occurrences of each username?

Comment: He's asking about number of occurences counting from the top for each row, not the number of elements in groups.

Comment: Do you have a column to sort the rows? if not, how to ensure the order of the items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with a combination of loop and [`Enumerable.Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), Something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    //Get count of current element to before:
    int count = list.Take(i+1)
                    .Count(r => r.UserName == list[i].UserName);
    list[i].Count = count;
}
```

Where your `list` is defined as:

```
List<User> list = new List<User>
    {
        new User{UserName = "A"},
        new User{UserName = "B"},
        new User{UserName = "A"},
        new User{UserName = "A"},
        new User{UserName = "B"},
        new User{UserName = "A"},
        new User{UserName = "C"},
        new User{UserName = "A"},

    };
```

and `User` class as:

```
public class User
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Later you can print the output like:

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine("UserName: {0}, Running Total: {1}", item.UserName, item.Count);
}
```

and you will get:

```
UserName: A, Running Total: 1
UserName: B, Running Total: 1
UserName: A, Running Total: 2
UserName: A, Running Total: 3
UserName: B, Running Total: 2
UserName: A, Running Total: 4
UserName: C, Running Total: 1
UserName: A, Running Total: 5
```

Comment: This is order n squared. Fine for small lists, but there are better approaches for large lists, or for enumerations coming from a database.

Answer (score 3):

Can it be done with LINQ? Probably not easily. Can it be done with your own extension method fairly easily? Sure (I haven't actually tried to compile and run the code so I can't guarantee that it'll work, but it's definitely a good starting point):

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, int>> RunningTotal<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    var counter = new Dictionary<T, int>();

    foreach(var s in source)
    {
        if(counter.ContainsKey(s))
        {
            counter[s]++;
        }
        else
        {
            counter.Add(s, 1);
        }

        yield return Tuple.Create(s, counter[s]);
    }
}
```

Comment: With some tweaks (edit in queue) it works very nicely indeed. Also the code can be further condensed if one so wants. add == false to the if, remove the else and incrementation and let counter[s]++ do the work. Other than that, a beautiful solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it **without double iterating** the set like this:-

```
        var values = "ABAABCA".ToArray();

        var counts = new Dictionary<char, int>();

        var counter = values.Select(ch => 
            { 
                int count = counts[ch] = counts.ContainsKey(ch) ? counts[ch] + 1 : 1;
                return new {ch, count}; 
            });

        foreach (var c in counter)
            Console.WriteLine(c.ch + " -> " + c.count);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this by using Select. I was writing a sync function that got items from the World of Warcraft API and certain items weren't on the API anymore, even though they technically were still in the game. Since I was syncing items in order of number of times they were listed on the auction house, it would get stuck on these certain items.

I created a list of bad item IDs. If the item wouldn't sync, I added it to the list. I wanted to skip the item if it couldn't sync 3 times. I accomplished that with the following code:

```
private int[] GetBadItemList()
{
    var ids = from i in _badItemIDs
              where _badItemIDs.Select(curItem => curItem.Equals(i)).Count() >= MAX_ITEM_TRYS
              select i;
    return ids.ToArray();
}
```