# How would i count the frequency of a number on an List<double> in C#?

Tags: c#, statistics, frequency

I have an `IList<double>` and i'm trying to find the most frequent value inside the list, as well as the frequency of each of the numbers on the list, but how would it work in a way that I get something like an `IDictionary<number, frequency>` of each value?

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you try any code for it ..??

Comment: Note that comparing `double` values is inherently tricky - are you sure that values you might consider to be "kinda equal" will actually be *exactly* equal?

Comment: I was trying comparing each value of the list with all the other values, but that way i would compare it with itself and all the duplicates too, would compare with all the other duplicates, and it would not work right, it should group the duplicates and the frequency of the value in a dictionary.

Comment: And no, the double value should only be equal when it is exactly the same, no aproximations.

Comment: A similar question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733278/count-occurrences-of-an-item-in-a-list-using-linq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var dictionary= list.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```